# sum value of property indise array of objects by key and return the same array but change sum value

Tags: javascript, typescript

Made code sample -

The array -

```
const arr = [
    {
        id: 1,
        name: 'daniel',
        city: 'nyc',
        sum: 10
    },
    {
        id: 2,
        name: 'daniel',
        city: 'nyc',
        sum: 20
    },
    {
        id: 3,
        name: 'daniel',
        city: 'nyc',
        sum: 30
    },
    {
        id: 4,
        name: 'daniel',
        city: 'las vegas',
        sum: 50
    },
    {
        id: 5,
        name: 'daniel',
        city: 'las vegas',
        sum: 100
    },
]
```

Reduce fuction -

```
      const map = arr.reduce(
        (acc: { [key: string]: number }, curr) => {
          if (
            acc[curr.name!] &&
            acc[curr.city!]
          ) {
            acc[curr.sum!] =
              acc[curr.sum!] + curr.sum!;
          }

          acc[curr.sum!] = curr.sum!;

          return acc;
        },
        {},
      );
```

Map function -

```
      const result = arr.map((item) => {
        return {
          ...item,
          quantity: map[item.sum!],
        };
      });
```

The result I'm getting -

```
[{
  "id": 1,
  "name": "daniel",
  "city": "nyc",
  "sum": 10,
  "quantity": 10
}, {
  "id": 2,
  "name": "daniel",
  "city": "nyc",
  "sum": 20,
  "quantity": 20
}, {
  "id": 3,
  "name": "daniel",
  "city": "nyc",
  "sum": 30,
  "quantity": 30
}, {
  "id": 4,
  "name": "daniel",
  "city": "las vegas",
  "sum": 50,
  "quantity": 50
}, {
  "id": 5,
  "name": "daniel",
  "city": "las vegas",
  "sum": 100,
  "quantity": 100
}]
```

What I try to achive -

```
     [{
  "id": 1,
  "name": "daniel",
  "city": "nyc",
  "sum": 10,
  "quantity": 60
}, {
  "id": 2,
  "name": "daniel",
  "city": "nyc",
  "sum": 20,
  "quantity": 60
}, {
  "id": 3,
  "name": "daniel",
  "city": "nyc",
  "sum": 30,
  "quantity": 60
}, {
  "id": 4,
  "name": "daniel",
  "city": "las vegas",
  "sum": 50,
  "quantity": 150
}, {
  "id": 5,
  "name": "daniel",
  "city": "las vegas",
  "sum": 100,
  "quantity": 150
}]
```

The logic is that if name and city are the same, sum the sum and apply it to all of the group with the same name and city (Need to match the groups by both name and city). I could not do it myself kept getting the sum in quantity. Would love to get some help thanks for any help

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this in two steps:

1. find totals for all cities
2. add corresponding total amount to each element

Try this way:

```js
const myarr = [
    {
        id: 1,
        name: 'daniel',
        city: 'nyc',
        sum: 10
    },
    {
        id: 2,
        name: 'daniel',
        city: 'nyc',
        sum: 20
    },
    {
        id: 3,
        name: 'daniel',
        city: 'nyc',
        sum: 30
    },
    {
        id: 4,
        name: 'daniel',
        city: 'las vegas',
        sum: 50
    },
    {
        id: 5,
        name: 'daniel',
        city: 'las vegas',
        sum: 100
    },
]

const addTotal = (arr) => {
  const totals = arr.reduce((prev, cur) => {
    if(!prev[cur.city]) {
      prev[cur.city] = cur.sum
      return prev
    }
    
    prev[cur.city] += cur.sum
    return prev
  }, {})
    
  const totalAdded = arr.map(el => {
    el.quantity = totals[el.city]
    return el
  })
  
  return totalAdded
}

console.log(addTotal(myarr))
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: What about checking if name is a match?

Comment: ``` if(!prev[cur.city]) {
      prev[cur.city] = cur.sum
      return prev
    }```

Comment: inside .map no need for a name check. The logic does not require

Comment: @devedvdevdev If this was helpful for you please do not forget to the answer mark as correct :)

Comment: What if there are another 3 fileds to check for the groups?
How can I check that?

Comment: What if the name was different, thats a criteria as well.
Also there are no types to your answer